# Is there a book that is best for learning gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to learn gazebo for turtlebots. But I am having difficulty finding the resources and documentation on turtlebots in gazebo. is there a particular book that I can buy to get in depth knowledge on gazebo?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242945/is-there-a-book-that-is-best-for-learning-gazebo?/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2016-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know about a book, but [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials) you can learn in depth about gazebo. Check the whole site.

P.S.: This question is not relevant to ROS, visit this [site](http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/). You probably will also get a better answer there.

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1